# create custom layout for sub menu in action bar

Tags: android, menu, submenu

I want to create a custom menu like Google play book. in fact I want when I click on a menu item in action bar show a custom layout that show somethings different from sub menu. I may put some object like seek bars or switches.
this is what I want:

http://www.andriman.com/media/other/Screenshot_2014-01-20-17-31-16.png

how can I do like that?

Comment: You can use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see what they use.

Comment: thanks, but uiautomatorviewer is a linearLayout. how to show this when click on a item in action bar. I know that the submenu can not be a container, it can just has an icon beside the text! I don't want this!